# Default Apppool in IIS 6.0?

Tags: .net, iis, application-pool

How can i check what version of .net is being used as DefaultAppPool in IIS 6.0 in Windows server 2003?
I tried to right click Properties of DefaultAppPool but didn't get any information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that setting resides at the virtual directory level in IIS6 (see screenshot) at link **[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okfhD.jpg)**

Comment: where can i find the virtual directory level?

Comment: if your app is in the site root - right click on "Default Web Site" and choose "Properties".  If your application is in a subfolder (iis application) right click on the folder underneath "default web site" where your application is installed and click "Properties"

Comment: i just don't see Default Web Site or the Virtual Directory Stie: http://i55.tinypic.com/2vmv67q.png

Comment: You have to expand the "Web Sites" folder to see the default web site, and then expand "Default Web Site" to see all virtual directories/iis applications beneath it

Comment: I don't see any Default Web site, there aer 5 sites but they are named other than Default Web Site.

Comment: OK, that is the same thing.  Someone just renamed or removed the default one.  If you right-click and choose "properties" on any of those sites, or any of the subfolders of those sites you should see a property dialog with the ASP.NET tab

Comment: Ok, not quite sure if this is how i am supposed to check. Under Web Sites folder there were 5 sites (or node). I clicked on first site(node) and found sub-sites. I clicked on one whose Application Pool was DefaultAppPool and checked the ASP.NET tab which should .net 1.1. Correct me if i did wrong.

Comment: @sanjeev40084 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1590/discussion-between-mjmarsh-and-sanjeev40084)

Answer (score 1):

The first ASP.Net application to start in the App Pool will determine the .Net Framework version used.  If you want to run ASP.Net 2/3/3.5 apps on the same IIS6 as ASP.Net 4 apps, put them in separate app pools.